How does a voltage transformer work under load?
I understand that under no-load conditions, a transformer behaves like a typical inductance coil with an impedance \$Z = j \omega L\$, essentially carrying only the magnetizing current \$I_\mu\$, which determines \$\Phi_\mu\$.
Under load, the secondary winding current \$I_2\$ creates its own flux, directed against the magnetizing flux. Consequently, this flux attempts to reduce the primary winding's main flux. However, the magnetizing flux must always remain, so the primary winding begins to draw more current, resulting in the magnetomotive force equation:
$$I_1 N_1 = I_2 N_2 + I_\mu N_1$$
The primary winding's inductive reactance seemingly decreases due to the secondary winding's magnetomotive force. Consequently, the self-inductance EMF of the primary winding should also decrease.
My question is: Where does the remaining voltage drop occur if the self-inductance EMF is diminishing?


Under load, the secondary winding current creates its own flux,
directed against the magnetizing flux.

Not really; consider the situation of the secondary load beings resistive. Then the secondary current is 90° lagging\$^1\$ the primary magnetization current but only acts against the new current taken by the primary due to adding the load. This means: -

The load currents (secondary and primary) multiplied by their respective number of turns are in opposition and produce a net core flux of zero
The magnetization current remains unchanged and, the flux in the core remains unchanged
This means that the output voltage remains unchanged.

OK this is slightly affected when you introduce more non-idealities like DC resistance of the windings and leakage flux but, it basically correct for an ideal transformer with finite magnetization inductance.

The primary winding's inductive reactance seemingly decreases due to the secondary winding's magnetomotive force.

No it doesn't and I don't know where you heard or read that. Surely you can see that a resistive load cannot possibly do that.

Where does the remaining voltage drop occur if the self-inductance EMF is diminishing?

The self-inductance of the primary and its associated EMF do not change. The extra current drawn into the primary is as a result of the conservation of energy. If this didn't happen then, taken to extremes, the universe would be very, very different.
\$^1\$ I say lagging because I'm using the input voltage on the primary as the 0° reference and clearly, if the load is resistive, the load current into the primary (ignoring magnetization current) is also at 0°. In other words, for loads (ignoring magnetization current) if current flows into the primary then current flows out of the secondary (180°).

The primary voltage drop is to generate the flux that counters the flux from the secondary current.

It occurs across the primary winding’s leakage impedance as the increased primary current under load causes greater voltage drops across the winding’s resistance and leakage reactance, so although the self-inductance EMF remains nearly constant (since flux stays constant), the additional voltage drop happens across the primary’s leakage resistance and reactance.
The core flux \$\Phi\$ and, consequently, the induced EMF \$E_1\$​ in the primary winding remain approximately constant, despite the opposing MMF from the secondary current. The increased primary current under load leads to higher voltage drops across the primary winding's leakage resistance \$R_1\$ and leakage reactance \$X_1\$. The remaining voltage drop you're asking about occurs across these leakage impedances, not due to a reduction in the self-inductance EMF.

so, does it turn out that the primary's inductive resistance drops or not?
